# The concurrency of the heights of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The sentence says that the opposite edges of the tetrahedron ABCD are perpendicular and the fact that  $AB^2+CD^2=AC^2+BD^2=BC^2+AD^2$ and I need to prove that the heights of the tetrahedron are concurrent, but I am stuck. I need a vectorial proof.[The picture of my solution so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8sGF.jpg)